# How to get color space of a jpeg/tiff in java?

Tags: java, image, colors, metadata, jpeg

the title sums it up really. Using the standalone exiftool program to dump all image metadata to a console I can see a line
Color Space Data : RGB
It looks like this is taken from the ICC-header

I want to get the same data programatically in java. I've tried the drew noakes library and the Sanselan library, but neither give me a value of RGB for any field.

Comment: Argh, I thought this was working after I had tried a
with a CMYK tiff and RGB jpeg but this fails badly for a CMYK jpg created in Photoshop, telling me it is RGB.

Answer (score 8):

You have a `BufferedImage`, right? If so, you probably want either [getType()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType()) or [getColorModel()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getColorModel())(then .[getColorSpace()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html#getColorSpace()) or .`toString()`). You can test getType() against the various types defined in `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Great! thanks, works for both jpg and tiffs that I've tried so far also.

Comment: For my own future reference, which one did you use?

Comment: toString() wasn't much use, so I did a switch on the type int against all the Constants in the ColorSpace class and generated my own human readable name Strings for each.