# Why are colors inverted when uploading a CMYK JPEG in Coldfusion?

Tags: image, file, coldfusion, upload, cmyk

I'm running `Coldfuison8` and have trouble with an image file upload, where I seem to often end up with users trying to upload CMYK JPEG files.

While the upload works fine (I don't get any errors) and `isImageFile` also returns `yes`, the colors of the loaded image are distorted.

Only doing this already saves the wrong colored image to the server:

```
<cffile result="temp" 
        action="upload" 
        accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg" 
        filefield="Dateiname8" 
        destination="#variables.tempDirectory#" 
        nameconflict="overwrite" />
```

**Question:**
If `isImageFile` does not produce an error, Coldfusion correctly identifies the image. What do I need to do to display it correctly?

**EDIT1:**
By distorted I mean, the file looks like this:

[image]

and ends up like this:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

```
<cfhttp timeout="45" 
    throwonerror="no" 
    url="#LOCAL.testFilePath#" 
    method="get" 
    useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12"
    getasbinary="yes" 
    result="LOCAL.objGet">
<cfset LOCAL.objImage = ImageNew(LOCAL.objGet.FileContent)>
<cfset LOCAL.ext = ".png">
<cfset LOCAL.basePath = LOCAL.tempDirectory & "_base_" & LOCAL.file & LOCAL.ext>
<cfset imageWrite( LOCAL.objImage, LOCAL.basePath, ".99")>
```

So, I'm splitting the filename into `file` and `ext` and then replace the extension with `.png`. The file gets created, but has 0 file size with the error thrown.

Any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT3:**
Here is my script using `imageMagick`:

```
<cffile result="temp" action="upload" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg" filefield="Dateiname8" destination="#variables.tempDirectory#" nameconflict="overwrite" />
<cfset variables.testFilePath = variables.tempDirectory & temp.serverFile>
<!--- imageMagick for CMYK uploads --->
<cftry>
    <cfimage action="info" source="#variables.testFilePath#" structname="cmyk" />
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cftry>
                <cfexecute name="#expandpath("../tools/imageMagick/convert.exe")#" arguments="#variables.testFilePath# -strip -colorspace rgb -quality 100 #variables.testFilePath#" timeout="30" variable="msg" />
                <cfcatch>
                    <cfdump output="dump.txt" label="catch" var="type: #cfcatch.type#">
                    <cfdump output="dump.txt" label="catch" var="message: #cfcatch.message#">
                    <cfdump output="dump.txt" label="catch" var="detail: #cfcatch.detail#">
               </cfcatch>
            </cftry>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    <!--- Image can now be read --->
    <cfimage action="info" source="#variables.testFilePath#" structname="cmyk" />
```

ImageMagick ran fine, but the image was still tainted. I then tried this:

```
<cfset variables.testFilePath = variables.tempDirectory & temp.serverFile>
<cfset variables.try = ImageRead( variables.testFilePath )>
<cfset ImageNegative( variables.try )>
<cfset ImageWrite( variables.try, variables.testFilePath, "0.99")>
```

And it created the correct image. Only problem is how to check for CMYK on the original image. Then I wouldn't need to use ImageMagick.

**EDIT4:**
And this is the full error I'm getting when trying to save the image as a png

```
Detail: Ensure that the file is a vaild image file.
Message: ColdFusion was unable to create an image from the specified source file.
StackTrace: coldfusion.image.ImageReader$UnableToCreateImageException: ColdFusion was unable to create an image from the specified source file.
at coldfusion.image.ImageReader.readImage(ImageReader.java:114)
at coldfusion.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:236)
at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ImageRead(CFPage.java:5841)
at cfform_img_handler2ecfc1184626149$funcUPLOAD.runFunction(E:123)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:453)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:320)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2222)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag(InvokeTag.java:358)
at cfhs_herstellerprofil2ecfm1153584487._factor19(E:559)
at cfhs_herstellerprofil2ecfm1153584487._factor21(E:514)
at cfhs_herstellerprofil2ecfm1153584487._factor22(E:511)
at cfhs_herstellerprofil2ecfm1153584487._factor41(E:502)
at cfhs_herstellerprofil2ecfm1153584487.runPage(E:1)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:282)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
TagContext:  ...    
Type: Application
```

[object of coldfusion.image.ImageReader$UnableToCreateImageException]
Class Name: coldfusion.image.ImageReader$UnableToCreateImageException

Parent Class: [object of coldfusion.image.ImageException]
    Class Name: coldfusion.image.ImageException

```
Parent Class: [object of coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationException]
    Class Name: coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationException
    Parent Class: [object of coldfusion.runtime.NeoException]
        Class Name: coldfusion.runtime.NeoException
        Methods:  
            findAdvancedCFTarget(coldfusion.runtime.AdvancedCFException, java.lang.String[]) returns int 
            findCustomTarget(coldfusion.runtime.CustomException, java.lang.String[]) returns int 
            findThrowableTarget(java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.String[]) returns int 
            getDetail() returns java.lang.String 
            getLocalizedMessage() returns java.lang.String 
            getMessage() returns java.lang.String 
            getRootCause() returns java.lang.Throwable 
            getString(java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.String, java.util.Locale) returns java.lang.String 
            getType() returns java.lang.String 
            setLocale(java.util.Locale) returns void 
            unwrap(java.lang.Throwable) returns java.lang.Throwable
        Parent Class: [object of java.lang.RuntimeException]
            Class Name: java.lang.RuntimeException
            Parent Class: [object of java.lang.Exception]
                Class Name: java.lang.Exception
                Parent Class: [object of java.lang.Throwable]
                    Class Name: java.lang.Throwable
                    Methods:  
                        fillInStackTrace() returns java.lang.Throwable 
                        getCause() returns java.lang.Throwable 
                        getLocalizedMessage() returns java.lang.String 
                        getMessage() returns java.lang.String 
                        getStackTrace() returns java.lang.StackTraceElement[] 
                        initCause(java.lang.Throwable) returns java.lang.Throwable 
                        printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter) returns void 
                        printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream) returns void 
                        printStackTrace() returns void 
                        setStackTrace(java.lang.StackTraceElement[]) returns void 
                        toString() returns java.lang.String
```

Comment: Convert it to RGB with something like ImageMagick? http://www.digitalrewind.com/post.cfm/cfimage-cmyk-workaround-rgb Due to limitations in the underlying java library, CF's support for CMYK is spotty at best ... Did you do a search on ColdFusion + CMYK. There are bunches of entries on it.

Comment: @Leigh: thanks. I just checked the non-installer version (don't have server access at the moment), which is 112MB. Do you know if I need all of this or would the `convert.exe` suffice?

Comment: You should check this post I made regarding [ColdFusion and Color Profiles](http://www.dansshorts.com/post/ie8-coldfusion-and-color-profiles). It describes the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: I am not sure. I have never tried a partial install. Give Dan's suggestion a whirl first and see if it works.

Comment: :-( I'm trying like in the edit above. Coldfusion complains `ColdFusion was unable to create an image from the specified source file`

Comment: @Leigh - tried both, what a f§$%&/ image. It's still tainted. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: What command did you use? Can you post the image/link? (Edit) The web version above appears to be RGB.

Comment: If you dump the LOCAL.objImage, is it returning the image object for you? Which line is failing, the ImageNew or the ImageWrite?

Comment: 1sec. Need to set it back up. I just tried running `ImageNegative` over the image and ... it works. Problem is how can I detect on upload if the image is tainted = how can I check for CMYK? I will try again with your answer and post on the error. Give me a few mins

Comment: Re *..with the error thrown.* What error? Post the full error and stack trace.

Comment: @Leigh: Error when trying to convert into png is in Edit4

Comment: ok, I posted to whole error when trying to convert into png. See my edit above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16665/discussion-between-leigh-and-frequent)

Comment: @Leigh - still there. I was running errants

Comment: You can use Java functions to check whether an image is RGB or CMYK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286959/how-to-get-color-space-of-a-jpeg-tiff-in-java I've not tried it myself, so YMMV.

Comment: It's more or less working now, but thanks anyway. I'm considerung just throwing an error on CMYK images. Just not worth the hassle, and I almost threw my iPad out of the window when I saw that after all this fussing, my had-hoped-for-solution (imageNegative if CMYK) still doesn't work.... = the image is negative on iPad...

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that one fell into the "if it sounds too good to be true..." category ;) About imageMagick, you should test it with more than just one image. `convert` is not perfect, but I did not have problems with it. So maybe there is something weird about that one image, like maybe it does not have an embedded profile or something? Can you post a link to the cmyk version? The one above reads as RGB for me.